# Hide Success Message

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am showing following code as successful updation of records. The user remains on the same Edit section & see's this `msg` just above `update button`.

I want this `msg` to disappear as user can still edit the records.

How to hide this `success msg`?

```
<div class="label label-success" data-ng-show="updateStatus">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up icon-white"></span>updated!
</div>
```

Comment: just assign falsy value to your updateStatus scope variable.

Comment: where to assign this value?

Comment: do you want to hide the message after a timeout (setTimeout()) or if the user edit something?

Comment: Anyone will do @CrisimIlNumenoreano

Answer (score 1):

Just add this after you add the success message

```
            setTimeout(function(){$('.label-success').slideUp();},3000);  //slidup after 3 second
```

the above code will slideup the message after 3 second

Comment: works...but only for 1st time.....so if user edits something again...the `msg` doesn't show up...

Comment: make a id of success message div, and then use that id for slidUp function, id should be different for different message div

Comment: more easier would be to have the success `div` in the html, and not by ajax , then use slideDown() to show the message , and the above code to hide the message after 3 second,in this way each success message would be shown the same `div`

Answer (score 0):

That message is only showing when you set `$scope.updateStatus` to `true` -- so after your AJAX, don't set this flag to `true` -- leave it as `false` and your message will never show.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                <label for="text">Text</label>
                 <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="text" required name="text" ng-model="user.text" **ng-change="OnChange()"** placeholder="Enter your text">
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input class="form-control input-lg" type="email" id="email" required name="email" ng-model="user.email"  **ng-change="OnChange()"** placeholder="Enter your email">
            </div>
```

Js side

```
$Scope.OnChange=function(){
     $scope.updateStatus=false;
     $scope.$apply();
   }
```

> Call this `ng-change="OnChange()"` to all field

or try this alert tag. You can delete the alert unneeded time.

```
<div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
  <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
  <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
</div>
```

js code

```
function AlertDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.alerts = [
    { type: 'danger', msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.' },
    { type: 'success', msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.' }
  ];

  $scope.addAlert = function() {
    $scope.alerts.push({msg: "Another alert!"});
  };

  $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
  };

}
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview